# Interpreting session activity

Tags: python, django

I am looking at my table for `django_session` and would like to know what this essentially means.

If I have 100 session entries in the past hour, does that mean 100 people have logged in in the past hour? Or does it mean something else?

Comment: not necessarily 100 people _logged in_; as dijango supports anonymous sessions, possibly whenever someone visits the site a new session starts until he closes the browser ... so if one user uses 2 browsers and visits your site, your site maintains 2 sessions

Comment: How would I know if a session is created when someone visits the landing page?

Answer (score 0):

If you put some data in `request.session` it automatically creates a record in `django_session` on `process_response` of session middleware. So if you put nothing in the session, and it stores only login data - then it will be number of logins (also by the same user - logount clears session data so it's being recreated if anyone logs in)

Answer (score 0):

It means there are 100 unique visting during which the request.session got modified. The unique visiting is based on per-user-browser: a user who uses Firefox and then Chrome to access your site **AND** having request.session modified during the process will be identified as two or more visting. Normally, there is no modification upon request.session thus no session entry will be generated. The default login page sets test flag in request.session, thus session entry will be generated for visitor, no matter whether he can log in successfully . Also, if a visitor denies cookie, his every access to the login page would generate a session entry.